# What kind of jazz (subgenre) does jazz24.org play?

Tags: identify-this-genre, jazz

Been listening to [jazz24.org](http://www.jazz24.org/) for a while and I can't place what kind of jazz they play.  It seems to cover a lot of eras but it's distinctive enough that I can almost recognize it from the music alone as opposed to other jazz stations.

Jazz comes in many subgenres.  I'm not even sure if what they play is a subgenre.  If there is some common thread please let me know.  Here's a sample of their playlist:

- First Sample

> Unchain My Heart
>   Ray Charles
>
> One Morning In May
>   Bill Charlap
>
> From This Moment On
>   Diana Krall
>
> Tino's Dream
>   Sax Gordon
>
> Someday My Prince Will Come
>   Dave Brubeck
>
> Max
>   Cory Weeds W/ Jeff Hamilton Trio
>
> Minor Swing
>   Django Reinhardt
>
> Sister Cheryl
>   Wynton Marsalis
>
> Summertime
>   Herbie Hancock / Joni Mitchell
>
> Song For Difang
>   Kenny Garrett
>
> Summer Night
>   Miles Davis
>
> 5-10-15 Hours
>   Ruth Brown
>
> Famous Are The Flowers
>   Geoffrey Keezer

- Second Sample (With album info)

> hello my lovely **Artist:** charlie haden **Album:** haunted heart
>   my one and only love **Artist:** johnny hartman **Album:** coltrane & hartman
>   what's going on **Artist:** charles lloyd **Album:** lift every voice
>   crazy **Artist:** tierney sutton **Album:** something cool
>   it's your thing **Artist:** jimmy mcgriff **Album:** straight up
>   hello **Artist:** cyrus chestnut **Album:** a million colors in your mind
>   your heart is as black as night **Artist:** melody gardot **Album:** my one and only thrill
>   in the afternoon **Artist:** wynton marsalis **Album:** marsalis standard time, volume one
>   insensiblement **Artist:** joe pass **Album:** best of joe pass
>   naima **Artist:** karrin allyson **Album:** ballads: remembering john coltrane
>   soul sauce **Artist:** poncho sanchez **Album:** soul sauce: memories of cal tjader
>   secret love **Artist:** joe beck **Album:** relaxin'
>   blues in the night **Artist:** katie melua **Album:** piece by piece
>   anna's blues **Artist:** benny green **Album:** live in santa cruz
>   i remember you **Artist:** coleman hawkins **Album:** desfinado
>   jumpin' at capitol **Artist:** nat king cole **Album:** best of nat king cole trio: instrumental classics
>   do it again **Artist:** sophie milman **Album:** in the moonlight
>   sweet sixteen bars **Artist:** ray charles **Album:** the best of ray charles
>   work song **Artist:** nat adderley **Album:** work song
>   lonely woman **Artist:** andy summers **Album:** the last dance of mr. x
>   tonk **Artist:** larry coryell **Album:** inner urge
>   you don't know what love is **Artist:** dinah washington **Album:** gitanes jazz
>   o pato **Artist:** charlie byrd **Album:** jazz samba
>   opus de funk **Artist:** horace silver **Album:** horace silver trio
>   red guitar **Artist:** cassandra wilson **Album:** another country
>   pent-up house **Artist:** sonny rollins **Album:** sonny rollins plus 4
>   this masquerade **Artist:** gene harris **Album:** listen here!
>   save your love for me **Artist:** joey defrancesco **Album:** all about my girl
>   winelight **Artist:** trio da paz **Album:** somewhere
>   slipped disc **Artist:** dave bennett **Album:** don't be that way
>   feeling good **Artist:** michael buble **Album:** it's time
>   stars fell on alabama **Artist:** tom scott **Album:** cannon re-loaded
>   born to be blue **Artist:** eric alexander **Album:** alexander the great
>   ham hocks and cabbage **Artist:** christian mcbride **Album:** out here
>   greasy spoon **Artist:** crusaders **Album:** southern comfort
>   when lights are low **Artist:** sarah vaughan **Album:** sarah +2

Comment: There's definitely a common sound to these selections, but it may be more of a shared sensibility than a single identifiable subgenre.  I started to write up an answer to this question, but too many of the songs were recognizably in different genres to make the answer worthwhile.  Maybe it means they have an actual human being making the selections, not a computer...

Comment: @ChrisSunami I can post more samples of their play list if it would help.  I'm interested in gaining this sensibility, even if it's a whole set of subgenres.  I'd like to learn enough to be able to go out into the world knowing what to ask for to get music like this.  I know just saying "Jazz" isn't enough.

Answer (score 3):

This is no one subgenre, but there are definitely parameters.  It's basically mainstream jazz of the years after Dixieland went out, but before smooth jazz was invented.  There's a lot of swing, some Chicago style, some bebop, some Hot Club (gypsy swing).  It's more small ensembles than Big Bands.  There's a lot of vocals (but no scat), and some soul mixed in.  There's a lot of newer artists, but only the ones who work in the traditional styles.  It's basically all acoustic, upright bass dominates.  There's some brass, and piano, but not much tuba or banjo.

There's no Louis Armstrong (Dixieland), no Kenny G (smooth jazz), no Monk (experimental), no Ellington (Big Band), no Ella Fitzgerald (scat).  The Herbie Hancock is acoustic, not electric or synthesized.

That should be enough to get you pointed in the right direction in a good record shop.